# Why does my Tkinter window background not change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've a small program with a feature to change the background color of a different window than the frame I use to ask for the background color. (I hope you understand this.) The program is written in Python with the Tkinter library.

Every time I click Enable in the window it changes the color of the background in the second window but not to the color I choose.

Where is the problem?

```
def Options():
def OptionButton():
    c= wert.get()
    if c == 1:
        fenster.config(background="red")
    elif c == 2:
        fenster.config(background="blue")
    else:
        fenster.config(background="yellow")


    global usermod
    usermod= tkinter.Entry.get(opEntry)

    fenster.update()
    option.destroy()

def close():
    option.destroy()


option=tkinter.Tk()
option.title("Options")
option.config(background="white")

#Backgroundframe
bgFrame= tkinter.Frame(option)
bgFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=20)

info3=tkinter.Label(bgFrame,text="Hintergrund im Menü")
info3.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10, pady=20)

#2 Radiobutton

global wert
wert = tkinter.StringVar()

knopfA=tkinter.Radiobutton(bgFrame,text="Red", variable=wert,value="1")
knopfB=tkinter.Radiobutton(bgFrame,text="Blue", variable=wert, value="2")
knopfC=tkinter.Radiobutton(bgFrame,text="green", variable=wert,value="3")



knopfA.grid(column=0,row=2)
knopfB.grid(column=0,row=3)
knopfC.grid(column=0,row=4)

knopfA.select()

#OptionFrame
opFrame = tkinter.Frame(option)
opFrame.grid(row=0, column=1,padx=10,pady=20)

#Optionbutton
oplabel=tkinter.Label(opFrame,text="Value User Mode")
oplabel.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=2)

opEntry=tkinter.Entry(opFrame,width=12)
opEntry.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=2)


#OptionButtonFrame
btFrame=tkinter.Frame(option)
btFrame.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,pady=20)

opbutton=tkinter.Button(btFrame,text="Enable", command = lambda:OptionButton())
opbutton.grid(row=1, column=0,padx=10,pady=2)

clbutton=tkinter.Button(btFrame,text="close",command=lambda:close())
clbutton.grid(row=2, column=0,padx=10,pady=2)

option.mainloop()
```

Comment: And sorry for that bad english in the question.... :D

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this code:

```
c = wert.get()

if c == 1:
        fenster.config(background="red")
elif c == 2:
        fenster.config(background="blue")
else:
        fenster.config(background="yellow")
```

The `.get()` method is returning a `str`, because you declared `wert` to be a `StringVar()` but you're comparing to an `int`.  Either convert via `int(c)` or compare strings:

```
if c == '1':
```

or perhaps declare `wert` to be an `IntVar()`.  Also, reread how the Python `global` statement works -- use it where you want to modify a global within a function, not where the global is defined.

Comment: It also doesn't work. I also tryed to change the values. The value of wert is always " "... Why is it like that?

Comment: @NextTV, I don't know what you mean by "the value of wert" but the value of `wert.get()` comes back as the string "1", "2" or "3" on my system.

Comment: On my system he gives me an empty value back... I don't know... Should i update python to the newest version? Which python do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring wert as a StringVar, you should declare it as IntVar because in your function OptionButton you're making the comparaison between a string and an int so it always entering in the else part so your background is always yellow.